# HP Zbook 15vG5 with Thunderbolt Dock G4 (USB C) - works in Ubuntu 19.04 but only parts in 18.04

Tags: usb, hp, dock

I have a HP Zbook 15vG5 with a HP USB-C Dock G4 (Thunderbolt) in use. In Windows and Ubuntu 19.04 everything worked fine.

Now I had to downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and now the Dock has some problems:

- (+) the 2 display ports work fine with the external screens
- (+) USB-Ethernet works fine
- (o) the front 2 USB 3 ports work fine but only with USB 3 devices! USB 2 devices don't work! (e.g. USB drives, wireless mouse dongle,...)
- (-) the backside USB 2 ports don't work at all
- (-) audio doesn't work

What could I try to get everything working again as in Ubuntu 19.04?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you have to do anything unusual to make the displays work?  I've got what claims to be an HP USB-C G4 dock and the Ethernet adapter and USB interfaces work but the displays don't show up.